# Add line break in Wordpress Post Title

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have long post titles in my wordpress website.

what I would like to do, is insert a line break so that the post title take up 2 lines.

I have been able to achieve this by using < b r >   (no spaces) within my post title.

The problem is now, that wordpress is duplicating my post title "background" image for the second line. So now there are two "rectangles" underneath each other - each with a line of text.

How could I prevent the post title image from duplicating, and keep both lines of text within the one rectangular post title image?

Thank you

Comment: could we see?  what is the URL of your website?

Comment: `Background-repeat: repeat-x;`?

Comment: @Torr3nt I tried Background-repeat: repeat-x   - now the rectangle is not repeating, but the text does not appear?  Here is a link [link](http://www.exoticdancers.co.za/stripperprofiles/malestrippers/johannesburgmalestrippers/)

Comment: @andi sure...   [web link](http://www.exoticdancers.co.za/stripperprofiles/malestrippers/johannesburgmalestrippers/)  Thank you

Comment: ack, NSFW!  warn me next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep your code which prints title in a single div.apply background image to this div only. then inside this div  use as many < br >, the image should not breakup.

Comment: Thank you.  the text now goes to the next line, but the second line is underneath the post title image?

Answer (score 7):

Add a comma in title and you could try to replace:

```
 `<?php the_title(); ?>`
```

with:

```
 `<?php echo str_replace(',','<br />',get_the_title()); ?>`
```

this replaces a comma , in the title with a html linebreak.

it's a logic try on yourself.

Comment: That works perfect for the title, but do you know how to do this to the secondary title ?